# How to add an addiitional health metric?

Tags: jhipster, spring-actuator

trying to add an additional health metric in my jhipster app.. what elase do I need to do other than the following ?

```
@Component
@RestControllerEndpoint(id="xxx")
public class CustomActuatorEndpoint {
    @GetMapping("/management/health/xxx")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity customEndPoint(){
        return  new ResponseEntity<>("REST end point", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but have you declared a HealthContributor bean?

Comment: I was following some tutorial but it never mentioned that. Can you point me to some good doc ?

Comment: Official doc? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators

Comment: I don't see anything in there about this 'Contributor' bean you are on about

Comment: Maybe you did not look enough, it says: Health information is collected from the content of a HealthContributorRegistry (by default all HealthContributor instances defined in your ApplicationContext). Spring Boot includes a number of auto-configured HealthContributors and you can also write your own.

A HealthContributor can either be a HealthIndicator or a CompositeHealthContributor. A HealthIndicator provides actual health information, including a Status. A CompositeHealthContributor provides a composite of other HealthContributors...